# "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, new-users

I got this error while updating a previously asked question on Stack Overflow:
[Getting error when importing from sibling package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45392900/4515198)

When I originally asked the question (and inserted over 6-7 links in it), I didn't get the above error at that time.

My reputation on Stack Overflow was 6, both at the time of asking the above question and when updating it.

Is this a bug?

Comment: 4 out of 6 links are to Stack Overflow, so they're not 'external'. I'm not sure if those count towards the limit or not.

Comment: @Glorfindel I added reference.

Comment: @iBug great, but I'm not 100% the OP's problem is now solved. He/she needs to tell us whether the updated content contains more than 2 *external* links.

Comment: Your SO posts are good. I have no idea why you don't have some hundreds of rep now. More exactly, I have...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No problem because **links to other questions and answers on Stack Exchange sites don't count**.

[image: Click to enlarge]

You see, only links 1 and 4 counted toward the 2-links limit. There's nothing wrong.

Reference [*Shadow Wizard*'s comment](/q/202877/)

> I believe links to any Stack Exchange site are allowed, only external links are limited.

An extra thing concluded from your own answer is that **Same link referred to multiple times counts as multiple links**.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @iBug for this information.

Made another revelation: the **link count** also includes the *number* of references to an external link.

So even if we use a **single** external link, if we refer to it more than twice, this error will be thrown.

E.g. the below image:

[image]

Even though I have a single external link at **1**, I have already referenced it twice earlier in the question. So referencing it again as **abc** is giving the error

Comment: In short: **Same link referred to multiple times counts as multiple links**.

Comment: @iBug, well concluded!

Comment: Let's get a quick and dirty fix for this. Now you have 11 rep and should be able to post more links.

Comment: very true @iBug, :D Many Thanks for the +5 rep!

Answer (score 0):

I'm calling this by-design; the restriction on the # of links is primarily a spam-discouragement thing, and for that purpose what matters is actually the number of links in the rendered output - not the number of unique URLs.

(SEO spammers occasionally try to cram a bunch of linked keywords into posts to increase the ranking for some site. Does it work? Probably not, but we still suffer for the attempt.)

Comment: Privileges section says they can't more than eight hyperlinks in a post or profile. But the count is only two. Is there something I am missing here?